# Dragged element appearing behind <md-tabs>

Tags: css, angularjs, drag-and-drop, angular-dragdrop

I'm having a button `md-tab- Drag-me` that have kept inside a tab. And am having another tab that needs to hold the dragged button.
Scenario:
When I try to drag the button it appears to go behind the tab.I need to ensure that it displays all the time whenever I start dragging and dropping ..
Please find the below example [demo on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZZVKp)

I have used [angular-dragdrop](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop) for dragging and dropping button.

Comment: Remove display: block property from <md-tabs> and try to arrange design  using other CSS properties.

Comment: @pooja can you please create a demo on codepen ?